# single layer/flatten pdf file ITEXTSHARP

Tags: itext

My Desktop App is creating a single page pdf with itextsharp library.There are 40 Passport size photos with names under it on a single page.

I need to flatten this pdf page (with 40 photos) as one Image while creating the pdf,currently there are 40 individual photos on the pdf page.I presume it would create around 80 layers by default which would take a very high time on ripping this file for printing on a press.

I dont want to make all the 40 images as one jpeg externally using GDI+ and then lay it in pdf.

I have seen many options using stamper and reading the created pdf file to flatten.Is there a way while creating the pdf i can create a flattened file.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of flattening a PDF is completely wrong. The concept of flattening a PDF means: removing all interactivity. For instance: you have a PDF file with form fields. The content of these form fields can be changed in Adobe Reader. When you flatten such a form, you take away the form fields and replace the field content by actual content of the page. The result is a flat PDF in the sense that people can no longer change the content of the fields.

You presume that having multiple pictures on a single page in a PDF means that there are multiple layers in that PDF. Your understanding of layers in a PDF is completely wrong. Layers is a word that is used in many different contexts. For instance, when working with optional content groups (OCG), people often refer to layers.

The concept of layers as you may know it from Photoshop doesn't really exist in PDF. Content is added in a stream. Whatever content is added first, can be covered by content that comes after. You want to pro-process the content by removing all the content that isn't visible in the hope that the PDF will be printed faster. You want to achieve that by replacing many different image objects by one image.

Your assumption that this can be done with iText is wrong. iText doesn't convert PDF to an image. This is outside the scope of what iText is written for.

If you want to add X images as 1 single image using iText, then you have to process the X images into 1 single image *before* you add the images to the PDF. You need image manipulation software, because iText won't do what you're asking for.

Comment: Thankx for reply,I come from a base of working with image editing softwares which has layers and flat pdf files.if the content is just one single page then the RIP would be faster.Is there any other pdf library that does this?

Comment: @LawrenceDias Not that I know of.